Has laravel 11 parameter like HOME in RouteServiceProvider?
All Laravel installations before 11 had RouteServiceProvider
class with constant defined:
public const HOME = '/admin/dashboard';

In manuals I did not find any similar functionality.
Has any?
UPDATED # 1:
Reading manual at https://laraveldaily.com/post/change-redirect-login-register-laravel-breeze :
I added OnlyGuestAllowedMiddleware middleware and added reference to in bootstrap/app.php file.
But checking content in OnlyGuestAllowedMiddleware:
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string ...$guards): Response
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    dd($guards);
    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(Auth::user()->getRedirectRoute());
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}

I see 1 element with null value. Why $guards is empty in my site? Where these options are set ?
UPDATED # 2:
I added manually in my Middleware 'web':
$guards = empty($guards) ? ['web'] : $guards;

But anyway Auth::guard($guard)->check() returns false
That is just after I logged into the app and I suppose that I must be logged.
Code ! empty(auth()->user()) also returns false
Actually code from bootstrap/app.php:
    $middleware->alias([
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\OnlyGuestAllowedMiddleware::class
    ]);

Raise doubts in me . I suppose 'guest' that is for ANY request, not only user logged into the app...
This hook seems not good.

Laravel 11 introduces some changes in the way routing and constants like HOME are handled in the RouteServiceProvider. As of Laravel 11, the HOME constant is no longer defined by default in the RouteServiceProvider class, and this is likely why you couldn’t find it in the official documentation.

Any hack decision ?

If you are upgrading from an old project you can still use your existing RouteServiceProvider, you can potentially also create your own RouteServiceProvider in a fresh L11 project and register it as a service provider the same way you would in older versions of Laravel.

@PetroGromovo , Can you please elaborate what does it show when you do dd($guards); ? Does it show null entirely or it shows null for a single element ?Please clarify.

Just   single element  with null

Please take a look at UPDATED # 2

Laravel 11 no longer relies on a predefined redirect value. Instead, the framework checks Middleware to see if the user is logged in and whether routes named dashboard or home are available. If either route exists, the user is redirected there. If not, Laravel defaults to redirecting to the root path (/). This approach gives Laravel more flexibility by handling redirects based on available routes rather than relying on hardcoded values like in previous versions.
For a detailed guide, check the full tutorial https://laraveldaily.com/post/change-redirect-login-register-laravel-breeze

Please take a look at UPDATED # 1

You can set the default guard to web instead of null.
// Set default guards if none are provided
$guards = empty($guards) ? ['web'] : $guards;

Thanks! But next operator Auth::guard($guard)->check() returns false. Why ?

Are you authenticated?

Yes, I use "laravel/breeze": "^2.2

Please take a look at UPDATED # 2

Create a temporary test route and temporarily disable the current middleware for testing purposes. Use this test route to verify if the user authentication is functioning as expected without interference from the middleware. !empty(auth()->user()) returns false because you're not properly authenticated.
